# Chrome DevTools Console to get all the texts in every page

Tags: google-chrome

I want to get all the texts in every pages without any HTML code, using Chrome Devtools Console. I really appreciate your help in advance.

The URLs go like this, changing A, B, C to Z.

```
http://www.imokorea.org/sub_03/03_05.asp?chk_on=m4&ACRO_1=A&ACRO_TYPE=1
http://www.imokorea.org/sub_03/03_05.asp?chk_on=m4&ACRO_1=B&ACRO_TYPE=1
http://www.imokorea.org/sub_03/03_05.asp?chk_on=m4&ACRO_1=C&ACRO_TYPE=1
http://www.imokorea.org/sub_03/03_05.asp?chk_on=m4&ACRO_1=Z&ACRO_TYPE=1
```

My code works only for the current page, not every page

```
function getText(){
    return document.body.innerText
}
function getHTML(){
    return document.body.outerHTML
}
console.log(getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

is your need $('html').html() ? or $('html').text()

Comment: I need text, not html. plain text that I need

Comment: I guess you can just do this with the help of regex